# Dynamic image publishing fails for similar file names

Tags: 2013-sp1, templating, dynamic-publishing, publishingfailed

We have created a dynamic CT to publish the multimedia components to the structure group that have same relative path as the folders using [this](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/publish-an-image-to-a-structure-group-mirroring-folder) example .

Everything works well except when we try to publish images with similar file names, were we get a ‘Committing Deployment Failed’ error.

The log :

> Attempting to deploy a binary 78675 to a location where a different
>   binary is already stored Existing binary: 78718:tcm:30-78267-32.

This happens even when the files are in different publications.

This publishing setup is fully on file system.

So investigating further, I found on CDS that the file(image)  is also created at `D:\data\binaryvariant\binaryurl` apart from the actual website folder. (`D:\data\` is the `defaultstorage path` in storage config and websites are at `D:\Websites\`)

This file in binaryurl folder is just 1kb and looks like a temporary file. However this is location where I believe I am getting the deploying error.

Strangely if I schedule publishing of all these multimedia components (with similar file names) at a same time, publishing works fine.

**Edit:**

Eg. Consider Multimedia Component MM1 with filename `Image.jpg` present in Pub A at Building Blocks - Content - Websitecontent. 
Publish this Component and it gets published to 
`D:\Websites\PubA\Websitecontent`

Consider another Multimedia component MM2 with same filename `Image.jpg` present in Pub B at Building Blocks - Content - Websitecontent. 
Publish this Component and it should be published to 
`D:\Websites\PubB\Websitecontent`. But it doesn't and  gives the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

The error message points to an issue where the filename of the published binary (`tcm:30-78675`) is equal to the filename of an already published binary (`tcm:30-78718`) in the same location.

Location and filename of published binaries are determined by the `AddBinary` call in your Template. The error message also indicates that the existing binary is using the Component Template `tcm:30-78267-32`.

Depending on your implementation, it sounds like you are using an override of `AddBinary` which does not postfix the published binary filename with the TCM URI, which would be a way to prevent this from happening. Could very well be a default publish binary TBB which you are using. Chris Summers discussed that in one of his (archived) blogs once: https://web.archive.org/web/20160402205904/http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx

Please note it might not be relevant because you didn't provide much detail on your implementation.

Comment: The binary publications in tridion are different from where I am publishing. Also as Chris explains, the issue would occur when tridion tried to publish multimedia at same folder 'Images'. Such is not the case here. In my case I believe the issue occurs because I am not using DB for storing binary metadata. Everything goes to filesystem. So the problem occurs in 'D:\data\binaryvariant\binaryurl folder where a replica of all images from different folders and publications are also saved. (just 1 KB as I mentioned).